# How to convert X items into array and looping

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 100k records. I want to create an array for each 10k items and loop this, i.e. first 10k items-> array(first 10k items), then seconds array(10k different items), then third and so on. In other words, each array contains 10k different records.

This is what I tried:

```
DECLARE
  i int64 DEFAULT 0;
LOOP
SET
  i=ROW_NUMBER() OVER();
IF
  MOD(i,10000) THEN
SELECT
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    item
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
  LIMIT
    100000) AS items;
    
END IF
  ;
END LOOP
  ;
```

This is the error I get:

> Query error: SELECT without FROM clause cannot use analytic functions
> at [5:5]

I also tried this:

```
DECLARE
  i int64 DEFAULT 0;
LOOP
SET
  i= (
  SELECT
    item,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER()
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`);
IF
  MOD(i,10000) THEN
SELECT
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    item
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
  LIMIT
    100000) AS items;
END IF
  ;
END LOOP
  ;
```

The error I get is:

> Query error: Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless
> using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values at [5:6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

```
with cte as
(
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn from `data-to-insights`.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw
limit 50
),
cte2 as
(
select rn,cast(floor(((rn - 1) /10)) as int64) as bucket from cte
)
select bucket,format("%t",array_agg(rn)) as array_of_rownumber 
from cte2
group by bucket
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: YES!!!!
i`m looking to create a loop that for each 10k items creates an array of those 10k items for the whole table i.e. each row is an array of 10k items

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for then please accept it. And Upvote. This motivates us to solve your questions.

Comment: i`m trying this now

Comment: so it gives me inside the array the same numbers but what i need is a specific field
i.e. i have a field named customer_email so i need the emails to be inside that array
so instead of numbers 1...50 it will show customer_emails

Comment: ok! thank you after changing few things in code it works !

Answer (score 0):

i`ll write here what i did for future reference

```
with cte as
(
select item,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn from `project.dataset.table`
limit 20
),
cte2 as
(
select item,rn,cast(floor(((rn - 1) /10)) as string) as bucket from cte
)
select  bucket,format("%t",array_agg(item)) as array_of_rownumber 
from cte2
group by bucket
```